# Connection Telegram and Discord bot to the same server

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I got an idea to develop Discord&Telegram bot for playing game. I am develop Telegram bot on Python and my friend do Discord bot on JS, we wanna use Heroku to host and run our server.but we don't have enough knowledge about infrastructure of projects like this. Can anyone briefly tell what we need to run two separated bots on one server? Main idea is you have access and can play using Telegram or Discord and your progress will sync.We thought to use data base and keep player progres in that db and share it between platforms

I run one worker on Heroku and it is doing well with my Telegram bot. But I have not idea how to tie thet together.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.